# How to get the id of a div from mouseenter function?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the id of the productbox div in this jquery code.i tried $this.attr('id) but the result is object object or undefined.how can i get the id of productbox div? thanks in advance

Javascript:

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', 'div.productbox', function() 
{
    buttonDiv = $(this).children('div.roll');
    myTimeout = setTimeout(function() 
    {
        Divid = ?;
        buttonDiv.toggle();
    }, 500);
});

$('body').on('mouseleave', 'div.productbox', function() 
{
    buttonDiv.hide();
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
});

$('body').on('hover', 'div.productbox', function() 
{
    var buttonDiv = $(this).children('div.roll1');
    buttonDiv.toggle();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="40" class="productbox">
    <span class="new">Yeni</span>
    <div class="roll" style="display: none;">
        <input type="button" value="139"> Like <input type="button" value="34"> Comment
    </div>
    <div class="productpicture" onclick="rload(40)">
        <img style="margin:auto; width:180px;overflow:hidden;display:block"  src="pictures/40.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="ps">
        <div class="productname">Giysi</div>
        <div class="companyname" onclick="go('2');">Koton</div>
        <div class="price">9.99 TL</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is not enough substance here to properly answer this question.

Comment: you should check my updated answer for the correct way on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of closure like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').on('mouseenter', 'div.productbox', function()
    {
        var $productBox = $( this );
        buttonDiv = $productBox.children('div.roll');
        myTimeout = setTimeout(function ()
        {
            Divid = $productBox.attr('id');
            buttonDiv.toggle();
        }, 500);
    });
    $('body').on('mouseleave', 'div.productbox', function ()
    {
        buttonDiv.hide();
        clearTimeout(myTimeout);
    });
    $('body').on('hover', 'div.productbox', function ()
    {
        var buttonDiv = $(this).children('div.roll1');
        buttonDiv.toggle();
    });
</script>

<div id="40" class="productbox">
    <span class="new">Yeni</span>
    <div class="roll" style="display: none;">
        <input type="button" value="139">
        Like
        <input type="button" value="34">
        Comment
    </div>
    <div class="productpicture" onclick="rload(40)">
        <img style="margin:auto; width:180px;overflow:hidden;display:block"  src="pictures/40.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="ps">
        <div class="productname">Giysi</div>
        <div class="companyname" onclick="go('2');">Koton</div>
        <div class="price">9.99 TL</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that is not the correct way, you just made $productbox a global variable that's bad practice.

Comment: no it's not, check my updated answer for how to correctly handle this problem. global variables are not the way to solve this.

Comment: @xorinzor $productBox is NOT global, as it is declared within an anonymous function. and is only available within that function. You can run this code in your browser and attempt to access $productBox outside of that function, and you will get an undefined error.

Comment: Fair enough, not a global variable. Still not the correct way on how to solve it though.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this:

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', 'div.productbox', function() {
    myTimeout = setTimeout((function(self) {
        return function() {
            buttonDiv = $(self).children('div.roll');
            Divid= $(self).attr("id");
            console.log(Divid);
            buttonDiv.toggle();
        }
    })(this), 500);
});
```

check the JSFiddle for complete working code: http://jsfiddle.net/kBRyu/2/

Comment: you did something wrong in your code in that case, example JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kBRyu/ if you are using google chrome you will see the id (40) appear in the javascript console on hover.

Comment: this one workds but it doesnt delay the operation for 500 it just does it and since i run a query to do that it kills the database.

Comment: works perfect! thanks for your effort. if i may ask one more question how can i add d to div.roll?                                             $.ajax({
                                          type: "POST",
                                          url: "handlers/getinfo.php",
                                          data: { ProductID:   Divid },
                                          dataType: 'json',
                                          success: function (d) {
                                         
                                    }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28566/discussion-between-xorinzor-and-tfeseas)

Comment: This is wrong, "self" in this case refers to the window, not the div you want the id of.

Comment: if you use console.log(self) you will see it actually refers to the div of which you are attempting to get the ID

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting 'undefined' etc is because you are actually requesting the window for its ID.

What you need to do is declare a local variable for the div and then inside your timeout use that variable to get the ID.

```
         $('body').on('mouseenter', 'div.productbox', function() {
             var $this = $(this);
             var buttonDiv= $this.children('div.roll');
             var myTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                 var Divid= $this.attr('id');
                 buttonDiv.toggle();
             }, 500);
         });
```

Comment: global variables are bad practice.

Comment: This does not create a global variable. The variable is local to the anonymous function.